# How to get full list of Rails' Geocoder city names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

How to get full list of Rails' Geocoder city names? I can get the city in English, using:

```
request.location.city
```

But I need the full list of English names for all cities in my country.

Comment: Geocoder allows to search for objects within a radius: obj.nearbys(30) But this is not a good solution because that is not what the geocoder was made for. It is better to get the cities from some other service or download a csv file and import it into db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem to get all cities of a country
https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities

```
cities = Cities.cities_in_country('GB')

#=> { "abberley"=> #<City:0x000001049b9ba0>, "abberton"=> #<City:0x000001049b9b50>, ... }

mcr = cities['manchester']
  #=> #<City:0x00000102fb4ea8>

mcr.name
  #=> "Manchester"

mcr.population
  #=> 395516

mcr.latlong
  #=> [53,5, -2.216667]
```